# Marketing Cloud : HTTPPost2 fails email validation

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, ampscript

In my email I am also making a POST request to an internal Marketing Cloud API to do additional actions. The particular function I am using is `HTTPPost2`, the whole POST request code works fine if I preview the email or send to a subscriber and the API action gets carried out.
However if I run the validation on an email, the last line after everything is prepared fails the validation.

```
/* SEND SMS */  
set @subscriberKey = AttributeValue("_subscriberkey")  
set @smsMessage = CONCAT('Your booking is at ', @timestamp, '. Dont be late!')
set @customerMobile = lookup("Account_Salesforce","PersonMobilePhone","External_ID__c",@CustomerId)
set @apiToken = "MY API KEY WILL GO HERE"
set @content = CONCAT('{
 "Subscribers": [{"MobileNumber": "', @customerMobile,'", "SubscriberKey": "', @subscriberKey , '"}],
 "Subscribe": true,
 "Resubscribe": true,
 "keyword": "TEST",
 "Override": true,
 "messageText": "', @smsMessage ,'"
}')

var @statusCode
var @response
set @post = HTTPPost2("https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/Mjo3ODow/send","application/json",@content,false,@statusCode, @response, "Authorization", CONCAT("Bearer " , @apiToken")
```

It is definitely something to do with the last line because as soon as I remove it the validation passes.

Comment: Hi, there appears to be something broken in the Concat function at the very end

Comment: CONCAT("Bearer " , @apiToken"). The last quotation mark is out of place and likely to cause the error.

Comment: You're right! Can you turn this into the answer thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the CONCAT("Bearer " , @apiToken") statement in the last line. The last quotation mark is out of place and likely to cause the error.